# Find out user who mounted a device in linux

Tags: linux, mount, user

Is it possible to find out in linux which user mounted a certain device?

After trying google I didn't find much information about this. I need to keep track about who mounted the ISO file which is used to install my software, so later if any update is needed this information is available and I can provide the user with a hint of which userID had this rights in the past.

Comment: IIRC `mount` even have hard-coded check on whether the user is root. Most likely you would want to check log/journal of sudo or polkit or so to see if you can find out which user has its privilege escalated to run mount.

Comment: Do you want to find out who mounted something with root rights, or who has a drive added (e.g. flash drive) and is accessing it under his UID?

Answer (score 0):

> Is it possible to find out in linux which user mounted a certain device?

Not intrinsically, no.

You *could* consider reviewing logs to determine who used `sudo mount -o loop ${PATH_TO_IMG}`, but **I would strongly advise against it**:

- It's going to be very unreliable (what happens if they `sudo`, then `mount` as root?)
- Will require lots of cross-system support and checks - where do you look?

  - `/var/log/auth.log`
  - `/var/log/security.log`
  - `journalctl`
- Will require handling different argument ordering and approach to the mount:

  - `mount ${PATH_TO_IMG} -o loop`
  - `losetup -f ${PATH_TO_IMG}` then `mount /dev/loop*`
- ... and probably a plethora other things I've not thought of

---

> I need to keep track about who mounted the ISO file which is used to install my software, so later if any update is needed this information is available and I can provide the user with a hint of which userID had this rights in the past.

It might be a better idea to just list out any users in the `sudo` / `wheel` group:

```
getent group sudo | cut -d: -f 4-
```

Or perhaps remember the value of `${SUDO_USER}` / `${SUDO_UID}` if it is set, and presuming that the user needs to be `root` to install your software.